# ¿Cómo puedo hacer un arreglo de checkboxes seleccionados en jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html5

Tengo estos checkboxes:

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Azul" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Rojo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Verde" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Amarillo" />
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer con **jQuery** un arreglo con los checkboxes marcados con **checked**?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```js
//Creamos un array que almacenará los valores de los input "checked"
var checked = [];
//Recorremos todos los input checkbox con name = Colores y que se encuentren "checked"
$("input[name='colores']:checked").each(function ()
{
//Mediante la función push agregamos al arreglo los values de los checkbox
checked.push(($(this).attr("value")));
});
// Utilizamos console.log para ver comprobar que en realidad contiene algo el arreglo
console.log(checked);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Azul" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Rojo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Verde" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Amarillo" />
```

Comment: Se puede generalizar a  `$('input:checked')` , aunque aqui pueden ir encerrados en un `<fieldset>`, por cierto los "name" y "id" deberian ser unicos.

Answer (score 2):

Una posibilidad es usar [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), cual te crea un array para los `checkboxes` seleccionados.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input:checkbox', getCheckedBox);

getCheckedBox();

function getCheckedBox() {
  
  var checkedBox = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), 
                         function(val, i) {
                            return val.value;
                         });
  console.clear();
  console.log(checkedBox);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Azul" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Rojo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Verde" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Amarillo" />
```