# ¿como hago para mostrar los resultados de checkbox activos o inactivos en la consola o almacenarlos en un array en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array, checkbox

Estoy trabajando en un código con `checkbox` y deseo que los resultados de cuales casillas se encuentran activas o cuales inactivas se muestren en la consola del navegador o se almacenen en un array al pulsar el botón guardar para posteriormente poder trabajar con ellas.
El código que tengo hasta ahora es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="divcontenedor">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="tipotex size30 center">Por favor Marque la opcion/opciones deseada:</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <form >
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 1</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck0" name="micheck">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 2</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck1" name="micheck">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 3</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck2" name="micheck">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 4</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck3" name="micheck">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="list-group-item">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 5</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck4" name="micheck">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/func.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo puedo hacer un arreglo de checkboxes seleccionados en jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36574/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-hacer-un-arreglo-de-checkboxes-seleccionados-en-jquery)

Comment: Creo que podrían existir ambas preguntas como _relacionadas_ ya que  esta abre la posibilidad a código con Javascript puro y eso marca una diferencia importante entre ambas @aldanux

Comment: @A.Cedano - Ni idea si es relacionado o duplicado... estoy confuso sobre ese tema... así que lo dejo para que decida la comunidad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Javascript (jquery 1.6+)**:

```js
function guardar() {
    var sel=[],nosel=[];
    $('form input:checkbox').map(function(){
        if($(this).prop('checked')){
          sel.push($(this).val());
        }else{
          nosel.push($(this).val());
        }
    })
    console.log("seleccionados");console.log(sel);
    console.log("no seleccionados");console.log(nosel);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Formulario</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Estilo.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="divcontenedor">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="tipotex size30 center">Por favor Marque la opcion/opciones deseada:</div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <form >
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12">
    <ul class="list-group">
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 1</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck0" name="micheck" value="micheck0">
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 2</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck1" name="micheck" value="micheck1">
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 3</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck2" name="micheck" value="micheck2">
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 4</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck3" name="micheck" value="micheck3">
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
     <li class="list-group-item">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-8">
        <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 5</p>
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-4">
        Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck4" name="micheck" value="micheck4">
       </div>
      </div>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
 </form>
</div>
<script src="js/func.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Para obtener otro valor que no sea el `value`, por ejemplo obtener el `id`, reemplaza esta sección:

```
if($(this).prop('checked')){
    sel.push($(this).attr('id'));
}else{
    nosel.push($(this).attr('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Pondré dos opciones, una con jQuery y otra con Javascript puro.

## jQuery

Una posibilidad es usando [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) de jQuery:

```js
$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {

  var siChequeados = $('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  console.log(siChequeados);


  var noChequeados = $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  console.log(noChequeados);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend>Elija opción</legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="1" />Opción 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="2" />Opción 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="3" />Opción 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="4" />Opción 4<br />
<hr />
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

---

## Javascript puro

Puedes usar [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (no funciona en navegadores antiguos).

Compatibilidad con versiones a partir de:

- Chrome 1
- Firefox 3.5 (1.9.1)
- IE 8
- Opera 10
- Safari 3.2

```js
document.getElementById("btnEnviar").onclick = function() {
  var siChequeados = new Array();
  var noChequeados = new Array();

  var checkboxs = 
  document.querySelectorAll('input[name="cbxTest"]').forEach(function(el) {

    if (el.checked) {
      siChequeados.push(el.value);
    } else {
      noChequeados.push(el.value);
    }
  })
  
  console.log(siChequeados);
  console.log(noChequeados);

};
```

```html
<legend>Elija opción</legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="1" />Opción 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="2" />Opción 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="3" />Opción 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="4" />Opción 4<br />
<hr />
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: No conocia map, sin duda mas rapido!

Answer (score 1):

Referente a la [respuesta original](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/36608/6491) tienes la posibilidad de usar [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/), cual te crea un array para los `checkboxes` seleccionados.

```js
$(document).on('click', 'input:checkbox', getCheckedBox);

getCheckedBox();

function getCheckedBox() {
  
  var checkedBox = $.map($('input:checkbox:checked'), 
                         function(val, i) {
                            return val.value;
                         });
  console.clear();
  console.log(checkedBox);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Azul" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Rojo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Verde" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" value="Amarillo" />
```

Y para los puristas de JS:

```js
getCheckedBox();

function getCheckedBox() {
  
  let checkedBox = [].filter.call(document.getElementsByName('colores'), function( cb ) {
  
    return cb.checked;
    
  }).map(function(cb) {
  
    return cb.value;
  });
  
  console.clear();
  console.log(checkedBox);
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" onclick="getCheckedBox()" value="Azul" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" onclick="getCheckedBox()" value="Rojo" />
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" onclick="getCheckedBox()" value="Verde" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="colores" onclick="getCheckedBox()" value="Amarillo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Reutilizando el código de otra pregunta a la que acabo de responder:

1. Primero recojo los valores y los guardo en un array.
2. Despues la imprimo en el campo de la modal.
3. Finalmente llamo a la modal.

Y respondiendo mas detalladamente a tu pregunta:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if(this.checked){
      valores.push(
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".opcion").text()
      );
    }
  });
```

Recorro todos los checkbox de la tabla verificando uno a uno si estan checkeados. Si es asi recojo su valor y lo introduzco en un array.

```js
function guardar() {
  var txt=$("#texto1").val();
  var valores = new Array();
  var sList = "";
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
    if(this.checked){
      valores.push(
          $(this).parent().parent().find(".opcion").text()
      );
    }
  });

  $( "#texto2" ).text(valores);
  $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
  
  <p>Por favor Marque la opcion/opciones deseada:</p>
  <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Opcion</th>
    <th>Seleccion</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="opcion">Opcion 1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="opcion">Opcion 2</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="opcion">Opcion 3</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="opcion">Opcion 4</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="opcion">Opcion 5</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
  <input type="button" value="enviar" onclick="guardar()" />
</body>
</html>
</div>



<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p id="texto2"></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript puedes comprobar el estado de un checkbox del siguiente modo:

```
document.getElementById('micheck0').checked;
```

Si está seleccionado devolverá `true`, por lo contrario devolverá `false`.

Teniendo los valores de los `checkbox` ya puedes meterlos en un array del modo que más cómodo te sea.

```js
function guardar(){
console.log(document.getElementById('micheck0').checked);
console.log(document.getElementById('micheck1').checked);
console.log(document.getElementById('micheck2').checked);
console.log(document.getElementById('micheck3').checked);
console.log(document.getElementById('micheck4').checked);
}
```

```html
<div class="divcontenedor">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="tipotex size30 center">Por favor Marque la opcion/opciones deseada:</div>                
        </div>
    </div>
    <form >
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ul class="list-group">
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 1</p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck0" name="micheck">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 2</p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck1" name="micheck">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 3</p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck2" name="micheck">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 4</p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck3" name="micheck">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <p class="tipotex size12">Opcion 5</p>  
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                Estado: <input type="checkbox" id="micheck4" name="micheck">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                  </li>                  
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button>
    </form>
</div>
```