# ¿Como mandar valores de los ckeckbox no seleccionados y seleccionados a un solo array (ya intente hidden) php?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mariadb

Hola de nuevo regreso con mi formulario esta vez tengo problemas con un checkbox por cierto ya intente lo del boton hidden que no soy tan flojo busque en google y funciono pero para un solo input pero me di cuenta que al enviar varios inputs me marcaba un error, ya que yo genero inputs de forma dinamica con jquery, agradeceria su ayuda para poder marcar el input con un valor por ejemplo "No" al no seleccionar el ckeckbox. Ya sea del lado cliente o del lado del servidor. Por cierto es un arreglo llamado etiquetado que quiero insertar en la base de datos.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10;
    var wrapper         = $(".container1");
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field");


    var x = 1;
    $(add_button).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){
            x++;
                var selectproductos = "<?php $sql = "Select producto from productos"; $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();

       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['producto'].'</option>';
       }
     ?>";

            var selectunidades = "<?php $sql = "Select unidad from unidades";

    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
       while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo '<option>'.$row['unidad'].'</option>';
       }
     ?> ";

          $(wrapper).children('table').append('<tr>   <td> <select required name="productos[]"><option value="">Selecciona un Producto</option>'+selectproductos+'</select><td><select required name ="unidad[]"><option value="">Selecciona una unidad</option>'+selectunidades+'</select></td><td><input type="text" class="inputancho" name="cantidad[]" placeholder="cantidad" required="required"/></td><td><input type="date"  name="fecha_de_embarque[]" required="required"/></td>  <td> <textarea  rows="2" cols="30" name="notas[]" id="notas" maxlength="255"></textarea> </td> <td><input type="checkbox" name="etiquetado[]" value="Si">   </td><td><a href="#" class="delete">Eliminar</a></<td></tr>'); //add input box

        }
  else
  {
  alert('You Reached the limits')
  }
    });

   $(wrapper).on("click",".delete", function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('td').parent('tr').remove(); x--;
})
});

</script>


<input type="hidden" name="etiquetado[]" value="No" />

<input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="GetTextValue()" id="submit-pedidos" value="Enviar" class="bt"/>


    </form>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que buscas algo [parecido a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100786/29967).

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero yo no quiero separarlos en diferentes arreglos, quiero que se guarden en un solo arreglo y que en ese se respete la seleccion que haga el usuario para cada valor, ademas no puedo cambiar el nombre del input porque despues lo utilizo en el post.

Comment: El título de tu pregunta dice que quieres guardar los valores de los checkbox no seleccionados... ¿es así? Si es correcto, modificando el código y dejando sólo la parte de `noChequeados` obtendrías lo que esperas. O sea,  con esto: `var noChequeados = $('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();` tendrías un array con los valores de los no chequeados.

Comment: Si los quieres todos juntos. Supongamos que todos tiene `name="nombre"`, haces esto: `arrDatos = $('input[name=nombre]').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(arrDatos);`

Answer (score 1):

Aquí te dejo dos posibilidades.

En una almacena los valores de cada input, en la otra almacena los valores y el estado (chequeado o no chequeado).

```js
$("#btnEnviar").click(function() {
  var arrTodo = new Array();
  var arrValores = $('input[name="cbxTest"]').map(function() {
    arrTodo.push(this.value, this.checked);
    return this.value;

  }).get();

  //Sólo Valores
  console.log("Sólo valores: " + arrValores);

  //Valores y estado
  console.log("Valores y estado: " + arrTodo);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<legend>Elija opción</legend>
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="1" />Opción 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="2" />Opción 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="3" />Opción 3<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="cbxTest" value="4" />Opción 4<br />
<hr />
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>
```

Comment: Este fin de semana ni lo intente pero este lunes he modificado tu codigo y al tratar de enviarlo por medio de post en PHP no he conseguido almacenarlo e insertarlo como si usara el name[] en html tanto para los checkbox seleccionados o sin seleccionar con sus respectivos indices ya que en mi base de datos cada registro tiene varios campos juntos jaja me siento frustrado