# ¿Cómo saber si un checkbox esta marcado?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Tengo un conjunto de checkbox y quisiera saber si está al menos uno marcado, cómo podría hacerlo, para que cuando me muestre una tabla que al momento está oculta con la propiedad hidden="hidden"
éste es mi código del diseño, pero no encuentro cómo saber cuando un checkbox esté marcado, y que se ejecute una acción. quiero que cuando uno esté marcado, se muestre una tabla, y cuando esté desmarcado se oculte de nuevo

```
  <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">
                                                        Preguntas 
                                                    </label>
                                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="visualizacionPreg">
                                                            <thead>
                                                                <tr class="heading">
                                                                    <th style="width: 10%">#</th>
                                                                    <th colspan="2" style="text-align: justify; width: 60%;">Pregunta</th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 10%;">Tipo</th>
                                                                    <th style="width: 20%;">Opciones</th>
                                                                    <th>Respuesta(s)</th>
                                                                    <th>Valor</th>
                                                                    <th>Negativo</th>
                                                                    <th>Prioridad</th>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </thead>
                                                            <tbody>
                                                            </tbody>
                                                        </table>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
```

aquí la tabla oculta

```
<div class="form-group">
<label class="control-label col-md-3">Notificar respuestas a </label>
<div class="col-md-9">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="Notificar" hidden="hidden">
<thead>
<tr class="heading">
<th class="table-checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#Notificar .checkboxes" />
</th>
<th>Id</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Correo</th>
<th>Puesto</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Intente ésto

```
$("#visualizacionPreg").find("checkbox").each(function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                alert("Hola")
            }
        });
```

Comment: que tienes echo en `js`?

Comment: perdón, ya acutalicé la pregunta, puse el método que intenté, pero no logro hacerlo funcionar

Comment: Veo que tienes los  `checkbox` dentro del `id="Notificar"` no dentro de `visualizacionPreg`

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, que quieres hacer?

Comment: El único `checkbox`  que tienes esta dentro de la tabla que esta oculta, te sugiero que replantees lo que quieres.

Comment: Tal como lo indica **@kacospro**, el objecto de tipo '`checkbox`' cuenta con una propiedad '`checked`' que te permitirá saber cuando la casilla es tildada.

Comment: [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100786/29967), si quieres puedes modificar la función, para que en vez de poner en un array los valores de los chequeados o los no chequeados, te devuelva `true` o `false` según encuentre al menos uno chequeado o no. La respuesta es particularmente útil si vas a usar los valores de los checkboxes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para saber si un checkbox está seleccionado puedes aplicarle un listener a los inputs de esta forma y realizar una acción según necesites

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
    if (this.checked) {
        console.log('Checkbox ' + $(e.currentTarget).val() + ' checked');
    } else {
        console.log('Checkbox ' + $(e.currentTarget).val() + ' unchecked');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="1">Checkbox 1</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="1" value="1">
<label for="2">Checkbox 2</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="2" value="2">
<label for="3">Checkbox 3</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="3" value="3">
<label for="4">Checkbox 4</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="4" value="4">
<label for="5">Checkbox 5</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="5" value="5">
<label for="6">Checkbox 6</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="6" value="6">
```

Answer (score 1):

Una función como esta hará el trabajo.

```
var c = () => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")).filter(cur => cur.type === 'checkbox' && cur.checked).length > 0;
```

Crear un array de un `objeto iterable`.

Lo filtras para saber si es un checkbox y si está chequeado, si es así `filter()` lo agrega al array.

Verificamos si el largo del array es **mayor** que 0, por ende el filter agrego al menos 1 elemento.

---

### Para hacer una acción según esto, puedes hacer algo como:

```js
var c = () => Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT")).filter(cur => cur.type === 'checkbox' && cur.checked).length > 0;



// Acciones a realizar


check.addEventListener("click", () => {
 if(!c()) { // Si NO hay ningun checkbox chequeado.
   console.log("Ningún chequeado..");
 } else {
   console.log("Al menos uno chequeado..");
 }
});
```

```html
Rojo: <input type="checkbox">
Verde: <input type="checkbox">

<input id="check" value="Comprobar" type="button">
```