# como valido un checkbox

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo una tabla con una lista de materiales y un check a un lado son parte de un formulario, lo que quiero es hacer que no se envié mi formulario hasta que todos los campos estén llenos junto con mi check , por que hasta el momento lleno el formulario pero se envía aun y cuando no e seleccionado ningún material cuano no e dado click a mi check

```
function valida(document)
{    
 if (document.check.value =="")
    {       
        alert("Indique el material de la cotización o pedido.");
        document.check.focus();
    return false;  }
}

<?php
$m=mysql_query("select id, material from material");
?>
<?php
if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
?>
<table class='mat' border='1'>
<tr><td>MATERIAL</td><td>Seleccione</td></tr>
<?php
while ($m1=mysql_fetch_array($m)) {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $m1[1];?></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='<?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?>' id='check' value=''/></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Verifica este enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129973/3092 y si tu check esta tildado (this.checked) haces que siga si no le mostras un mensaje de que tiene que tildarlo en el else

Comment: sigo sin poder validar el formulario se envía aunque  no hay nada checked

Comment: Subi el codigo del formulario, para que ande como te comento no tendrias que tener un boton submit tendrias que desde el boton llamar a la funcion que valide y si todo esta correcto hacer un onSubmit del form

Comment: if (document.getElementById("check").checked==false)    
    {      
        alert("Indique el material de la cotización o pedido.");
        document.getElementById("check").focus();
    return false;
  }

Comment: <input type='checkbox' name='<?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?>' id='check' '/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para validar todos los checkboxes en el codigo javascript debes buscar por el nombre, no por el id (que deberan ser distintos por las regras del HTML). El nombre de la lista de checkboxes deberia ser el mismo para todos los campos del material:

```
<table class='mat' border='1'>
<tr><td>MATERIAL</td><td>Seleccione</td></tr>
<?php
while ($m1=mysql_fetch_array($m)) {
?>
<tr><td><?php echo $m1[1];?></td><td><input type='checkbox' name='material' id='<?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?>' /></td></tr>
<?php 
}
?>
</table>
```

La function para validar seria:

```js
function validate() {
    var values = document.getElementsByName("material");
    for(var i=0; i < values.length; i++){
     var checked = values[i].checked;
        if(!checked) {
         alert("Error"); return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: el nombre no pueden ser el mismo ya que los nombre son aleatorios cambian respecto a la variable que  obtengo aqui name='<?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?>'

Comment: este atributo **name** debe ser utilizado para identificar el campo (en su caso un conjunto de campos) y no el valor del material. Para eso utilice el atributo **value**. intente poner el codigo <?php echo "mat".$m1[0]?> en este atributo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que podrías hacer es un formulario y llamar una función de js para validar que todos los campos han sido llenados.

```
<form name="formulario" action="" onsubmit="return validate()" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input id="checkbox" name="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<form />
```

Y la función en js:

```
function validate() {
    name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    checkbox = document.getElementById('checkbox');

    if (name == null || name.length == 0) {
        console.log('Error');
        return false;
    }
    else if( !checkbox.checked ) {
        console.log('Error');
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Si la validación pasa, los datos se enviarán a donde diga el formulario, si no pasan, te mostrará un error en pantalla.

Una de las mejores prácticas es que las validaciones la realice el servidor al recibir datos, por que el usuario puede desactivar el JS o modificarlo del lado del cliente, pero espero te sirva.

Es solo un ejemplo, saludos!