# Activar boton con javascript al clickar en un <a>

Tags: javascript

Esto es lo que he intentado

```
<a class="step_block" onClick="activar()" href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer">
</a>

   <script language="javascript">
       function activar(){
          document.getElement.ById('buttone').disabled = false;
        }


    </script>

<form action="<?php echo $result ?>">
<button id="buttone" disabled="true" style="background-color:#26a69a;" target="_blank" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Proceed to target site</button>
</form>
```

También me gustaria que fuera al clickar dos botones no uno :). Un saludo

Ahora mismo el problema de este código es que la etiqueta disabled = false no desactiva si no que sigue igual. (Da igual que pongas disabled=pepito que va a estar desactivado)

Mi codigo actual

```
<div class="all_steps">
<a data-clickado="false" class="step_block" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer" data-clickado="false">
<div style="background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/DhSqcGy.png')" class="step_left"></div>
<div class="step_content"><h2 style="text-align:left;">Subscribe</h2>
<p style="text-align:left;">Subscribe to <?php echo $refername; ?> to proceed.</p>
</div><div class="step_arrow"></div>
</a>
<br>
<a data-clickado="false" class="step_block" href="https://twitter.com/intent/follow?" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer">
<div style="background-image:url('https://i.imgur.com/TlYkMkc.png')" class="step_left"></div>
<div class="step_content"><h2 style="text-align:left;">Follow</h2><p style="text-align:left;">Follow <?php echo $refername; ?> to proceed.</p></div><div class="step_arrow"></div></a> </div>
<br>
<form action="<?php echo $result["shortenedUrl"] ?>">
<button id="buttone" disabled="true" style="background-color:#26a69a;" target="_blank" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Proceed to target site</button>
</form>
<div class="card_share">
</div>
</div>
</section>
<?php
require('inc/service.php');
require('inc/footer.php');
?>
<script language="javascript">

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Cuando la pagina termine de cargar, anadimos los eventos a los botones.

    document.querySelectorAll('a[data-clickado]').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', activar);
    });
  });


   function activar(e){

      let salir = false;

      e.target.dataset.clickado = true; // Guardamos el data para saber que el boton ha sido activado

      document.querySelectorAll('a[data-clickado]').forEach(el => {

          if (!salir && el.dataset.clickado === 'false') {

              salir = true; // En caso en que falte un boton por activar avisamos a la variable

          }

      });

      if (!salir) document.querySelector('#buttone').disabled = false; //activamos el boton si esta todo bien

    }


</script>
```

Comment: ¿No es más simple usar `checkboxes` en este caso?. Escuchas cada cambio y activas el botón únicamente cuando todos estén seleccionados. Sería algo parecido al [segundo fragmento de código mostrado aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/136663/29967). En él se determina cuando están todos desmarcados, sería sólo cambiar la lógica a *todos marcados*. El problema que veo con los elementos del tipo `a` es que te obliga a guardar en un atributo `data` los estados del click, en cambio con un `checkbox` no haría falta. Además, con el elemento `a` es complicado saber si se revertió el click...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primero comentarte, que el metodo para encontrar un elemento por id es `getElementById()`. Aunque es más recomendable utilizar `querySelector()`.

La solución a tu fallo:

```
<a class="step_block" onclick="activar()" href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer">Boton1
</a>

   <script language="javascript">
       function activar(){

          document.getElementById('buttone').disabled = false;

        }


    </script>

<form action="<?php echo $result ?>">
<button id="buttone" disabled="true" style="background-color:#26a69a;" target="_blank" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Proceed to target site</button>
</form>
```

Una manera de implementar que sean 2 o el numero de botones que quieras:

```
    <a class="step_block" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer" data-clickado="false">Boton1
    </a>

    <a class="step_block" href="javascript: void(0)" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer" data-clickado="false">Boton2
    </a>



    <form action="<?php echo $result ?>">
    <button id="buttone" disabled="true" style="background-color:#26a69a;" target="_blank" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Proceed to target site</button>
    </form>

<script language="javascript">

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    // Cuando la pagina termine de cargar, añadimos los eventos a los botones.

    document.querySelectorAll('a[data-clickado]').forEach(el => {
      el.addEventListener('click', activar);
    });
  });


   function activar(e){

      let salir = false;

      e.currentTarget.dataset.clickado = true; // Guardamos el data para saber que el boton ha sido activado

      document.querySelectorAll('a[data-clickado]').forEach(el => {

          if (!salir && el.dataset.clickado === 'false') {

              salir = true; // En caso en que falte un boton por activar avisamos a la variable

          }

      });

      if (!salir) document.querySelector('#buttone').disabled = false; //activamos el boton si esta todo bien

    }


</script>
```

Comment: No me funciona :(. Lo he probado tambíen en un documento aparte copiando lo que has puesto y nada, al dar click en los dos no se activa

Comment: La primera si funciona pero la segunda no :(

Comment: Perdona, habia unas erratas, ya deberia funcionar la segunda

Comment: Ahora me funciona separado, pero no en mi codigo, nose que error estoy cometiendo. :)

Comment: He actualizado la pregunta con el codigo que puse incluyendo el tuyo

Comment: Gracias por ayudarme :)

Comment: Para que funcione en el ejemplo que has puesto, cambia `e.target` por `e.currentTarget`. Al tener elementos hijos en la a, el target apuntaba a estos. Con este cambio deberia irte. Lo cambio tambien en la respuesta para que veas donde es

Comment: Vale ya va gracias de verdad :)

Answer (score 2):

Veo algunas cosas que están mal puestas, como el `onclick` y el `document.getElement`

```
<a class="step_block" onclick="activar()" href="" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noreferer">
</a>

   <script language="javascript">
       function activar(){
          document.getElementById('buttone').disabled = false;
        }
   </script>

<form action="<?php echo $result ?>">
<button id="buttone" disabled="true" style="background-color:#26a69a;" target="_blank" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">Proceed to target site</button>
</form>
```

El evento `onclick` lo he puesto en minúscula y en `document.getElementById` te sobraba un punto.

Comment: Gracias :). Ahora voy a intentar hacerlo con dos