# ¿como activar y desactivar un boton con jsavascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo dos botones la idea que uno esté desactivado hasta que el se le de click al que este activo y este se active

Comment: que has echo hasta ahora?

Comment: Hola Francisco, ¿Podrías mostrarnos el código que estás intentado hacer?

Comment: hasta ahora solo eh tenido la idea, pero no eh desarrollado el código, eh visto un par de ejemplos de como activarlo pero con dos text input pero mi idea es hacerlo con dos botones uno que este descativado hasta que se haga onclick en el activo

Comment: Hola Francisco, necesitamos que nos enseñes lo que intentas para ayudarte. Pero si no sabes por donde empezar, esta pregunta tiene un problema similar, quizas pueda guiarte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/245946/activar-boton-con-javascript-al-clickar-en-un-a/245949#245949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Buen día, quizá te ayude este código:**

```js
$('.jsBtn_1').on('click', function(){
   //Removemos el atributo 'disabled' del segundo botón, apenas se detecte un click en el primer botón
   $('.jsBtn_2').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="jsBtn_1">Botón 1</button>
<button class="jsBtn_2" disabled>Botón 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta necesita mejoras, le idea es que intentes primero realizar tu mismo el objetivo, y si no logras encontrar un modo de hacerlo puedes pedir ayuda aqui mostrando lo que has trabajado hasta el momento para tener una guia.

Aqui te dejo una solucion bastante sencilla que talvez te ayude; haciendo click en `Botón 2` activas y desactivas el `Botón 1`.

Los botones tienen un atributo `disabled` que al aplicarlos evita que se pueda hacer click en el boton; aqui simplemente estoy creando una funcion en el evento `onclick` del Boton 2 para que agregue o elimine este atributo

```js
document.getElementById('btn2').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('btn1').toggleAttribute('disabled')
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">Botón 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Botón 2</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No me quedó claro tu pregunta, pero aquí te dejo una pequeña guía de como puedes realizar esa acción de activar o desactivar botones con javascript.

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
var activarDesactivar = document.getElementById('activarDesactivar');
activarDesactivar.onclick = function() {
  if(btn.disabled){
    btn.disabled = false
    btn.firstChild.data = "Habilitado"
    activarDesactivar.firstChild.data = "Deshabilitar"
  }else{
    btn.disabled = true
    btn.firstChild.data = "Deshabilitado"
    activarDesactivar.firstChild.data = "Habilitar"
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Habilitado</button>
<button id="activarDesactivar">Deshabilitar</button>
```