# recoger y guardar los checkbox chekeados con jquery y ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

hola tengo que recoger los checkbox que esten checkeados para filtrar unos resultados , lo estoy realizando mediante ajax.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                  <label for="inputState"><strong>Estrellas</strong></label><br>
                  <label for="">1<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="1" id="checkbox_uno"></label>
                  <label for="">2<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="2" id="checkbox_dos"></label>
                  <label for="">3<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="3" id="checkbox_tres"></label>
                  <label for="">4<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="4" id="checkbox_cuatro"></label>
                  <label for="">5<input type="checkbox" name="ch" value="5" id="checkbox_cinco"></label>
                </div>
```

y este es el codigo de jquery

```js
function estrellas(){

  var ckbox = $("input[name='ch']");
  var chkId = '';
  var ar=[];
  $('input:checkbox').on('click', function() {
    ar.splice(1,2);
    if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
      $("input[name='ch']:checked").each ( function() {
        chkId = $(this).val();
        chkId = chkId.slice(0,-1);
        ar.push($(this).val());
      });
      console.log(ar);
      $.ajax({
      url:'php/ch.php',
      type:'POST',
      dataType:'JSON',
      data:{ch:JSON.stringify(ar)},
      success:function(resp){
      console.log(resp);
    },
    error:function(error){
    console.log(error);
  }
})
}
});
}
```

cuando inserto los que están checkeados en el array me los duplica y si les quito el check se me siguen guardando , alguna sugerencia?

Comment: [Aquí tienes dos formas muy simples de hacerlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/100786/29967), una con jQuery y otra con Javascript puro mediante `querySelectorAll`. Allí se pedía recoger  los chequeados y los no chequeados, si sólo te interesa uno u otro, omites la parte que recoge los que no te interesan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo mas compacto de tu función

```
var ar=[];
$("input:checkbox").change(function() {
   ar.length=0;
   $("input:checkbox").each ( function() {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
         ar.push($(this).val());
      }
   });
   //aqui se añade tu funcion para guardar la info
});
```

Tambien te dejo el enlace para que lo revises
https://jsfiddle.net/00c08yu2/

Comment: Gracias es justo lo que necesitaba !